# Create variable of Model class in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have model `EmailModel` class model :

```
    export class EmailModel {

    public name: String;
    public lastname: String;
    public address: String;
    public company: String;
    public zipcode: number;
    public city: String;
    public phonenumber: number;
    public email: String;
    public product: ProductModelOrder[] = [];



    constructor(name: String, lastname: String, address: String, company: String, zipcode: number, city: String, phonenumber: number, email: String,product: ProductModelOrder[]) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.address = address;
        this.company = company;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
        this.city = city;
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
        this.email = email;
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

And I created the variable  `emailModel` of my class `EmailModel`.
This is my var:   `emailModel =< EmailModel>{};`

I get the undefined error  when I using the `this.emailModel.product`, but when I using the `this.emailModel.name` or other properties everting is well.

Comment: Like this : `emailModel =< EmailModel>{};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initilize array to be as empty array like this in order to use like normal property of object -

```
public product: ProductModelOrder[] = [];
```

Comment: Thanks this sole problem.

Comment: Could you please see my updated `EmailModel` class, I have the same error and it is very strange

Comment: for me working fine, see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adug2r, can you reproduce your issue here?

Answer (score 1):

The product attribute is an array of "ProductModelOrder" and should also be initialized

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is your class definition, other thing is instantiating your object.
Your class definition looks alright.

Now lets try to instantiate:

```
let products: ProductModelOrder[] = []; //Creates an instance for the array of products
let product: ProductModelOrder = new ProductModelOrder(...); //Creates an instance for a product
product.someproperty = "somevalue"; //Sets value to property
products.push(product); //Adds the product to the list

let emailModel = new EmailModel(..., products); //Instantiates the main object, passing the instantiated array

console.log(emailModel.products[0].someproperty);//Logs the value of the property "someproperty", in this example it should print "somevalue".
```

Please note that I have renamed the property EmailModel.product to EmailModel.product**s**
because it can contain many products.

Comment: Thanks for this example is useful.